# How can I keep milk from spoiling and/or turning yellow?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

I am trying to find a way to keep milk from spoiling and/or turning yellow.

Apparently there is a process for achieving this, and I am aware that there is a lady who creates milk beads for resin jewelry and she claims that she is able to prevent the milk from spoiling/yellowing over time.

I have heard that you can add baking soda to milk to preserve it, but this lady also claims that she adds nothing to the milk and that it simply undergoes a "process".

Of course, she won't share her secrets, so **my question is**:

What are the different ways in which milk can be preserved while preserving the white color?

Comment: Pasteurization is probably what is meant.